# How to plot dygraph in Knitr markdown in for loop ? Knitr_child is not working

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to plot the dygraphs in for loop in Knitr. So I used `Knitr_child()` method, in which I define my graph but it's not working when it has been called from main .Rmd file.